# How to stop WPF drag and drop from locking dropped file

Tags: wpf, file-io, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop application (which allows users to organize their files) that takes files.  The app keeps a list of strings that corresponds to the files, but it does not need access to the files themselves.  The problem is that the program locks files like the application has them open.  How can I release them?

```
private void File_Dropped(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        return;

    var files = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
    ImageFile iFile;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (_Extensions.Contains(IO.Path.GetExtension(file).ToUpper()))
        {
            iFile = new ExtendedImageFile(new StringBuilder(file).ToString());
            LBXFiles.Items.Add(iFile);
        }

    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: i think the problem is not in this class... Its more possible that in the class ExtendedImageFile you open a file handler which you dont close anymore

Comment: Thanks.  That's it.  I thought the code i was using inside the constructor automagically released any file locks, but it looks like it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fantastic fix lived up to his name.  See the commend on the original post